Creating my own custom thread pool executor
I ran into an issue here while creating my own custom thread pool executor. I am trying to implement the same without making use of any executor service library in order to prepare for a java interview. I am able to code below service.
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Worker extends Thread {
    private final Queue<Runnable> taskQueue;
    private volatile boolean isStopped = false;

    public Worker(Queue<Runnable> taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!isStopped) {
            Runnable task = null;
            synchronized (taskQueue) {
                while (taskQueue.isEmpty() && !isStopped) {
                    try {
                        taskQueue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    task = taskQueue.poll();
                }
            }
            if (task != null) {
                task.run();
            }
            if(isStopped)
            return;
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        isStopped = true;
        interrupt(); // Interrupt the thread if it's waiting
    }
}

public class CustomThreadPool {
    private final int poolSize;
    private final Queue<Runnable> taskQueue;
    private final Worker[] workers;

    public CustomThreadPool(int poolSize) {
        this.poolSize = poolSize;
        taskQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        workers = new Worker[poolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Worker(taskQueue);
            workers[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        synchronized (taskQueue) {
            taskQueue.offer(task);
            taskQueue.notifyAll(); // Notify all waiting threads to start executing the task
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            worker.stopThread();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomThreadPool threadPool = new CustomThreadPool(3);

        // Submit tasks to the thread pool
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            int num = i;
            threadPool.execute(() -> {
                int result = calculateFactorial(num);
                System.out.println("Factorial of " + num + " is " + result + " - Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
        }

        // Shutdown the thread pool
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }

    private static int calculateFactorial(int n) {
        int factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        return factorial;
    }
}


Below is the output of the code above.
Factorial of 1 is 1 - Thread: Thread-0
Factorial of 2 is 2 - Thread: Thread-1
Factorial of 3 is 6 - Thread: Thread-2

Well the problem here is that I am submitting 5 tasks to the executor , i can see the same in the taskQueue as well, but only 3/5 tasks are being executed as the threadpool size is kept 3. I want these 3 threads to run those 5 tasks in someway. I need help to understand what i am doing incorrectly and how to force the same 3 threads to execute all the provisioned tasks in the queue.

I think the problem is that you shutdown the thread pool before the workers are able to execute all tasks. So you are most likely exiting all the workers with isStopped being true and not when the queue is empty.

Side note: Your if(isStopped) return; within a method solely consisting of a while(!isStopped) … loop is obsolete.

An interrupt means someone wants your thread to stop what it’s doing and exit cleanly, as soon as possible.  Ignoring an interrupt is the worst possible response.  The easiest solution is to put the entire while (!isStopped) loop inside the try/catch.

Based on this answer, I would modify the run() method like this:
public void run() 
{
  while( true )
  {
    Runnable task = null;
    synchronized( taskQueue )
    {
      if( isStopped && taskQueue.isEmpty() ) break;
      if( taskQueue.isEmpty() )
      {
        try 
        {
          taskQueue.wait();
        } 
        catch( final InterruptedException e ) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if( !taskQueue.isEmpty() ) task = taskQueue.poll();
    }
    if( task != null ) task.run();
  }
}


thanks for this too mate , yours seem more thread safe but that while(1) got me thinking.

@AdityaTiwari – In Java, while(1) would not compile  . But of course you can store the result of the check in the line with the break to a variable and use that as the while condition. But to move the check on the taskQueue to the while will not work when that check should be synchronized.

You are stopping workers when isStopped == true even if there are still jobs to process.
Minimal change to your code would be, to modify run method like this
    public void run() {
        while (!isStopped || !taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Runnable task = null;
            synchronized (taskQueue) {
                while (taskQueue.isEmpty() && !isStopped) {
                    try {
                        taskQueue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    task = taskQueue.poll();
                }
            }
            if (task != null) {
                task.run();
            }
        }
    }


Not the best idea to call taskQueue.isEmpty() outside the synchronized block, but the chance for trouble should be marginal.

Thanks mate! This worked out fine. I should've seen this earlier. The worker thread already had its isStopped flag set to true hence it could not take undertake another task. This taskQueue.isEmpty() came handy for the completion of tasks in the queue.
